# SQL: select between delimiters with delimiters itself, insert in other column and delete string

Tags: mysql, sql, delimiter

Instead of having one column for each group of values, I made one column named "data" and used HTML like this:

```
<dt>Phone:</dt><dd>0 23 16/3 82 73 42 23</dd>
<dt>Phone:</dt><dd>0 21 61/81 26 73 13 22</dd>
<dt>Fax:</dt><dd>03 27/3 87 42 37 32</dd>
<dt>Website:</dt><dd>www.example.com</dd>
```

Now, I recognized, that wasn't very clever and I made a column for each value. My new columns names are "phone", "phone2", "fax" and "website".

I need an SQL code for e.g. selecting all between the delimiters `<dt>Phone:</dt><dd>` and `</dd>` and the delimiters itself, insert this string in the column "phone" and delete this string in the "data" column.
But I need to select the first string `<dt>Phone:</dt><dd>0 23 16/3 82 73 42 23</dd>` not the second `<dt>Phone:</dt><dd>0 21 61/81 26 73 13 22</dd>`.

Can anybody give me a hint how to do that?

Comment: If you want to choose the destination column based on what is contained within the `<dt>` tags, then I think you'll need dynamic SQL for this.  It might be easier to sort this out, from outside MySQL.

Comment: No, I don't want. I'll do it manually. But, how to select between the delimiters `<dt>Phone:</dt><dd>` and `</dd>` and insert into `phone` column?

Comment: Look into using `INSTR` for MySQL.  This, combined with substring, might allow you to do this.

Answer (score 0):

For selecting data between `<dt>Phone:</dt><dd>` and `</dd>` you can use SUBSTRING_INDEX.

Like this

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(data, '</dd>', 1), '<dt>Phone:</dt><dd>', -1) as phone,
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(data, '<dt>Phone:</dt><dd>', -1), '</dd>', 1) as phone2,
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(data, '<dt>Fax:</dt><dd>', -1), '</dd>', 1) as fax,
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(data, '<dt>Website:</dt><dd>', -1), '</dd>', 1) as website
from data_col;
```

Update:

> `<dt>Phone:</dt>` is not always in top.

in case if there is no specified order of data in "data" column, try this one:

```
SELECT
    IF (temp.f_phone > 0, SUBSTR(data, temp.f_phone + LENGTH('<dt>Phone:</dt><dd>'), f_phone_end - temp.f_phone - LENGTH('<dt>Phone:</dt><dd>')), null) as PHONE_1,
    IF (temp.s_phone > 0, SUBSTR(data, temp.s_phone + LENGTH('<dt>Phone:</dt><dd>'), s_phone_end - temp.s_phone - LENGTH('<dt>Phone:</dt><dd>')), null) as PHONE_2
  from data_col dc
JOIN (
  SELECT id, @f_phone:= LOCATE('<dt>Phone:</dt><dd>', data) as f_phone,
  LOCATE('</dd>', data, @f_phone+1) f_phone_end,
  @s_phone := LOCATE('<dt>Phone:</dt><dd>', data, @f_phone+1) as s_phone,
  LOCATE('</dd>', data, @s_phone+1) as s_phone_end
from data_col) temp ON temp.id = dc.id;
```

First find the starting position of each possible element (e.g. "phone"  "phone2") and a position of closing tag `<\dd>`. And than use `SUBSTR` from starting position of element + length of delimiter, with `length = end_position - start_position -  delimiter_length`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. To make it easier I suggest to focus on a single string. This is my actual code `SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(data, '</dd>', 1), '<dt>Phone:</dt><dd>', -1) as phone FROM data_col;`. Unfortunately I'm also getting data that aren't inside this delimiters. How can that be?

Comment: Could you please show the answer that returns when you run this query?

Comment: E.g. in one data_col filed there's only `<dt>Website:</dt><dd><a href="http://www.example.de"> www.example.de</a></dd>`. This gots selected with your code. Why that?

Comment: try `if else` to check is there such delimiter `SELECT IF (LOCATE('<dt>Phone:</dt>', data)!= 0, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(data, '</dd>', 1), '<dt>Phone:</dt><dd>', -1), '') as phone FROM data_col;`

Comment: Hi @Kokin Vadim, thank you for your answer and please sorry my late reply. Unfortunately it's still not working with you latest code: This code also outputs `<dt>Something:</dt><dd>&nbsp;` as result sometimes.

Comment: So there is no any specified view of data in this column? Is it possible that `<dt>Phone:</dt>` goes after `<dt>Something:</dt>`? For example `<dt>Website:</dt><dd>www.example.com</dd><dt>Phone:</dt><dd>0 23 16/3 82 73 42 23</dd>`

Comment: Yes you're right. `<dt>Phone:</dt>` is not always in top. Does it matter?

Comment: Hey Kokin, smeds to work, thank you very much. But how to insert this in my "phone" column and delete this selected and inserted string in my "data" column?

Comment: It seems to me that in this case the mysql stored procedure is the easiest way to select data, insert it and than delete. Or you can create Insert|Delete queries using `CONCAT` (like this `SELECT CONCAT('INSERT INTO table_name (phone, phone2....) values (', query_to_select_phone,',', ...,  ');')`)